# Seeking a Cocoa Touch elements framework

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, element

It had many iOS ui elements programmed into it for use like table views with text fields, unobtrusive alerts, etc... I've been searching all over and cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any library that matches exactly what you're asking for, but the reasonably-popular three multi-component libraries I'm aware of are:

- [**three20**](https://github.com/facebook/three20)
- [**Tapku**](http://tapku.com/)
- [**SSToolkit**](http://sstoolk.it/)

If they don't have what you need, the most comprehensive sites that catalog iOS libraries that I know of are:

- [**CocoaObjects**](http://cocoaobjects.com/category/platform/license-ios/)
- [**CocoaControls**](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls)

If you can't find what you're thinking of on one of those two sites, it's quite possible that it doesn't exist.

Comment: fond what I was looking for in Cocoa Controls. Thanks!